# How to get the geometry and SRID in SQL View GeoServer REST API?

Tags: geoserver-rest-api, sql-view

I am trying the create the GeoServer SQL View using GeoServer REST API. Here is my XML configuration file,

```xml
layer_xml = """<featureType>
        <name>{0}</name>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <namespace>
            <name>{5}</name>
        </namespace>
        <title>{0}</title>
        <srs>EPSG:{6}</srs>
        <metadata>
            <entry key="JDBC_VIRTUAL_TABLE">
                <virtualTable>
                    <name>{0}</name>
                    <sql>{1}</sql>
                    <escapeSql>true</escapeSql>
                    <keyColumn>{2}</keyColumn>
                    <geometry>
                        <name>{3}</name>
                        <type>{4}</type>
                        <srid>{6}</srid>
                    </geometry>
                </virtualTable>
            </entry>
        </metadata>
        </featureType>""".format('demo', sql, 'gid', 'geom', 'Geometry', 'demo', 32642)
```

I am sending a post request to this URL,

```
http://localhost:8080/rest/workspaces/demo/datastores/postgis/featuretypes
```

Here is my SQL query,

```sql
SELECT * FROM demo.table1 as table1
LEFT JOIN demo.table2 as table2
ON table1.id=table2.id
```

I tried with the GeoServer GUI and published the layer. It is working perfectly fine. When I try to add the layer using the above configuration, It loads successfully but is unable to find the Native SRS as in the below image,

[image: native SRS empty image]

When I try to visualize the WMS using layer preview, it throws me an error as below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM "http://203.159.29.45:8080/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.1.1/WMS_exception_1_1_1.dtd"> <ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1" >   <ServiceException>
      java.lang.RuntimeException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Premature end of file.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Premature end of file.
Premature end of file.
</ServiceException></ServiceExceptionReport>
```

So my question is, is there any way to get the geometry and SRID of the SQL view using GeoServer API?

**Edit:**

I tried with another dataset and found that the Native SRS was not the issue. The `layer_xml` with the above `POST` request works perfectly.

Now, my question is, instead of providing the SRID through the XML file, is there any way to guess the geometry and SRID of the SQL view using GeoServer API same as in GeoServer GUI?

[image: guess geom geoserver]

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file. I suspect that the problem is unrelated to the native SRS. Another check is to create a SQL View in the GUI and inspect the results of a GET request to see if you are missing something from your XML.

Comment: Thank you very much @Ian. My problem was with the style file (generic style). I corrected my SLD file and now it started working. The last and just a minor thing, is there any way to get the actual SRID of the SQL query so that I don't neet to submit the SRID in my XML file? I mean can I implement the `Guess geometry type and srid`  button functionality similar to geoserver GUI using GeoServer REST API?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible, again I'd check the XML of one you create through the GUI

Comment: Hi @IanTurton, I send the SRID through my request XML and now it is working fine. Thank you very much. PS: I have edited the question as well.

Comment: You have no answer yet so it is an ideal to heavily revise your question so that it asks only your current question.